# Windows Phone 8.1 FileIO.WriteTextAsync Access Denied

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a file in InstalledLocation. I want to write some text to this file. When i run from visual studio, there is no problem in my device, I can write or read file. But when i install app from store, i can't write. It occurs an error saying that 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'.

I checked the capabilites section in Package.appxmanifest but i didn't see anything like 'write, read authority' or something like that.

Please see code below.

```
  StorageFile htmlFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("mobile.html");

  await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(htmlFile, form.MobileHtml);  // I am receiving error here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Your app doesn't have write access to its install location. Instead write your editable data to the app data folders (ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder or RoamingFolder).

Unfortunately because of the way apps are installed for test from Visual Studio they do get write access then.